# XSLT sort by node name then attribute name and then by attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to sort an XML

- first by tag names, then by
- each of its attribute names and then
- the attribute values should be sorted

For e.g.:

Would like to sort an XML by its tag name first, then by its attribute name and then by the attribute value.

For e.g. for the below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    

<myroot>
        <mychild id="123">
            <fruit>apple</fruit>
            <test hello="world" testing="removed" brackets="angled" question="answers"/>
            <comment>This is a comment</comment>
        </mychild>

        <mychild id="789">

            <fruit>orange</fruit>
            <test brackets="round" hello="greeting">
                <number>111</number>
            </test>
            <dates>
                  <modified>123</modified>
                  <created>880</created>
                  <accessed>44</accessed>
            </dates>
        </mychild>


        <mychild id="456">
            <fruit>banana</fruit>
            <comment>This will be removed</comment>
        </mychild>
    </myroot>
```

XSLT should produce the below output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myroot>
   <mychild id="123">
      <comment>This is a comment</comment>
      <fruit>apple</fruit>
      <test brackets="angled"
         hello="world"
         question="answers"
         testing="removed"/>
   </mychild>
   <mychild id="456">
      <comment>This will be removed</comment>
      <fruit>banana</fruit>
   </mychild>
   <mychild id="789">
      <dates>
         <accessed>44</accessed>
         <created>880</created>
         <modified>123</modified>
      </dates>
      <fruit>orange</fruit>
      <test brackets="round" hello="greeting">
         <number>111</number>
      </test>
   </mychild>
</myroot>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does "*sort by each of its attribute names*" mean? Your example shows you want to sort the attributes by their names - but why is   `<mychild id="456">` moved ahead of `<mychild id="789">`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k pardon my incorrect use of terminology if its wrong

Comment: @michael.hor257k pardon my incorrect use of terminology if its wrong.              In this eg id is an attribute name and 456 is the attribute value for the tag mychild.  id=456 was moved up because its greater than id 123 and less than id 789

Comment: The logic is still not clear. If an element has more that one attribute, which attribute's name - or value - should it be sorted by? Note that by definition, the order of attributes has no significance, so you could easily get different results using different processors.

Comment: @michael.hor257k if an element has more than one attribute then the attributes has to be sorted. Logic is if the tag names are same then the first attribute name should be compared , if the attribute name is same then the value should be used , if the first attribute and its value are same then the second attribute should be considered , if all the attributes and value are same then the child noted should be considered.

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes XSLT 2.0 is supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the below xslt is working :-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

    <xsl:template match="*">

        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">        
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
                <xsl:sort select="." />
            </xsl:apply-templates>

            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/> 
                <xsl:sort select="." />
                <xsl:sort select="text()" />

            </xsl:apply-templates>


        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   



    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will sort based upon the attributes also:

```xml
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          version="1.0">
          <xsl:output indent="yes" />
          <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
          <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:copy> 
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">        
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/> 
            </xsl:apply-templates>
              <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
                <xsl:sort select= "name(@*)"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:template>
         <xsl:template match="@*">
            <xsl:copy />     
          </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```